# Matplotlib: How to make equal aspect permanent

Tags: matplotlib

Every time I need to make the aspect ratio of the plot to `equal` in matplotlib, I have always to use:

`plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')`

How can I make this change permanent for future plots (Is it possible to save it in `matplotlibrc` file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the aspect via `rcParams`. The only option for a "global" aspect would be to monkey-patch the Axes class like this:

```
import matplotlib.axes

class MyAxes(matplotlib.axes.Axes):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._aspect = "equal"
matplotlib.axes.Axes = MyAxes
```

Then,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3], [0,10,20])
plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: There is a problem when I use `plt.legend()`

Comment: I can potentially help with any problem for which I have a [mcve] available. I don't see any link to your code here, so currently that's impossible.

Comment: When I try to reprodure a minimal example, the issue is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `from mpl_toolkits imprt mplot3d` are at the top of the file when I comment them it seems to solve the issue on the example but that doesn't work with my code.

Comment: Yes, for this solution to work you need to first monkey-patch, then import pyplot.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that whole code. If you can reduce it to some 20 lines I can investigate further.